# How to 'hide' column in Matrix Visual if no field parameter is selected

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create a fully customizable matrix table in Power BI.

The matrix has field parameters for rows, columns and the values:

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to hide the columns if nothing in the column field parameter is selected? (and thereby only show values and rows in the matrix visual)

I've found a workaround that I fear is not intuitive for the user.
For the column field parameter, if I select one of the dimensions as is already selected as a row dimension, the columns will disappear and only the selected value along with the selected rows will be shown (exactly how I want it):

[image]

The issue with this method of hiding the columns is that as soon as something else is selected as rows, the columns will appear again. One could just select the same new row dimension for the columns to make them disappear again, but I want to know if there is a better way that might be more intuitive for the user.

An alternative solution is to use bookmarks to switch between a matrix and table visual, but I would like to know if my goal can be achieved with a matrix visual.